# Confidence intervals computed after a model selection

Tags: machine-learning, confidence-interval, model-selection

I read this sentence in my example sheet on R : "any inferential procedures computed after and from the same data used for model selection are not valid".

Could someone explain this sentence ? I do not understand why this is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theory behind confidence intervals (CIs) states that if the model is true with true parameter $\theta$, say, then the CI will cover the true parameter in 95% of cases in which it is computed (assuming 95% is the confidence level). So the idea is that such a CI is computed again and again and again from different independent datasets with a certain true parameter value. Now this can no longer hold if you decide from looking at the data whether you want to compute it or not. How exactly this plays out depends on how you make your decisions, and because this is subjective, one cannot formalise it in a precise way. However, if for example you'd be interested in having 0 in the CI, and you only compute it if the data looks like zero may be a good value, this means that you will have zero very often in the CI even if it is not the true parameter.

On the other hand, if you run a test (which is also an inferential procedure and in this respect works somewhat similar to CIs) for the $H_0: \mu=0$ (for a normal mean $\mu$, say) *only* if the data give you the idea that zero may be wrong, then you will reject the $H_0$ almost always even if it is occasionally true, and the theory that you should only reject in, say, 5% of cases will be invalidated.

Imagine somebody who wants to test that homeopathy works better than a placebo and runs several studies, but only actually computes the test if the data gives them the impression that homeopathy indeed did something good here, which even by accident may happen once in a while. Obviously this person using those data to state that "homeopathy works" should not be trusted. (Please note that I have no information that this happens more often with homeopathy than elsewhere - anyway, it happens all over the place and is bad.)

PS: You may wonder whether this is a problem if you made your data dependent/model selection decision in a different way, not obviously favouring or dismissing particular parameter values. The answer is that we cannot know, because unless you specify precisely in advance what you will be doing, it cannot be formally analysed. Therefore inference is formally invalid, and how big the problem is depends not only on how precisely you made your decision, but also on how you'd make this decision in general, on other datasets, because only then one could figure out error probabilities, effective confidence levels etc.

PPS: In fact if you use an automatic model selection procedure that is specified before seeing the data, this kind of thing can be analysed, and there is some work on such things in the literature. However it is complicated, and the first message is that standard inferential procedures that don't take the model selection into account will not normally work, and will need to be adjusted, and in a handful of cases such adjustments exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I think it is clear. In my case, we used forward selection with AIC to select a submodel (i.e select covariates for a glm model with a binomial family). Then, we compute confidence intervals for the coefficients associated to the covariates obtained. If I understood your commentary well, we cannot compute confidence intervals in this case because basically we chose the "best model" regarding our procedure and our data and, then we look at confidence intervals. But in this case it is not a 95% confidence interval (or X% in general) because we could not have

Comment: Exactly. If you do forward selection first, you'll systematically choose covariates with coefficients substantially different from zero, so zero will be less often in the CIs than it should be.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help